# Transposing, rotating, and combining 2D arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D array, and it size is 93 X 93.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 93

arr2D = np.eye(size, size, dtype=float)
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        arr2D[i][j] = np.arctan((i+1)/(j+1))

arr2D = np.cos(arr2D)

plt.imshow(arr2D)
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.0455)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to create 4 same arrays, transpose, and combine them (size: 186 X 186) to make them look like the figure below, how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could use NumPy's [`concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html?highlight=concatenate#numpy.concatenate) function for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [np.flipud](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) and [np.fliplr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) for flipping and [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [np.c_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) for stacking

```
stacked_arr = np.c_[np.fliplr(arr2D),arr2D]
stacked_arr_flipped = np.flipud(np.c_[np.fliplr(arr2D),arr2D])
new_arr = np.vstack((stacked_arr_flipped ,stacked_arr ))

plt.imshow(new_arr)
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.0455)
plt.show()
```

[image]